# Using l'Hopital rule for $\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{1}{x\exp(x^{-2})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help putting this in $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over xe^{x^{-2}}}$$

I've tried every possible combination, and I don't get what I'm missing. Using a graphic calculator, you easily see that the $\lim_{x\to 0}$ of this function is $0$.

Comment: You don't use L'Hopital's rule here.

Comment: If you mean $\frac{1}{xe^{x^2}}$, then as $x \to 0$, this function clearly diverges to $\pm \infty$, since it goes toward $\frac{1}{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=1/x$ and compute separately the limits from the right and from the left:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x\exp(x^{-2})}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{\exp(t^2)}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{2t\exp(t^2)}=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x\exp(x^{-2})}=
\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{t}{\exp(t^2)}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{t\to0\infty}\frac{1}{2t\exp(t^2)}=0
$$

If you try to do it in one step, by rewriting the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\exp(-x^{-2})}{x}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2x^{-3}\exp(-x^{-2})}{1}
$$
you fall into a worse situation as before.

The alternative way would be rewriting the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1/x}{\exp(x^{-2})}
$$
but here you need to separate the two limits, because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist. This is essentially what I did above with the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this answer is based on OP's first post. There have been several revisions of the original post. I think you mean $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{1}{xe^{x^2}}$, and for this case is a little more challenging to you since the original limit does not exist. You can for this one write: $\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{x}$, and proceed with L'hospitale rule twice. Hint: answer $ = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hôpital's rule is not needed here.

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}=\frac{1}{e^0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$, we only need to consider the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ part. And clearly, this is $\pm\infty$.

Comment: The person who had edited my formula did a mistake. The equation was e^x^(-2). 0^-2 is impossible